# Intuition behind probability amplitudes, probabilities and Bloch sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

In mathematics, let’s assume the original basis is $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.
We can write $(1,1)$ as a linear combination of the original basis: $(1,1)=x(1,0)+y(0,1)$ where $x=1$, $y=1$.
Also we can write $(1,-1)$ as a linear combination of the original basis: $(1,-1)=x(1,0)+y(0,1)$ where $x=1$, $y=-1$.

Now let’s assume $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ is the new basis.
We can write any vector let’s say $(2,1)$ as a linear combination of the new basis: $(2,1)=x(1,1)+y(1,-1)$ where $x=\frac32$, $y=\frac12$;
also acknowledging that $(2,1)$ can also be written in the original basis as $(2,1)=x(1,0)+y(0,1)$ where $x=2$, $y=1$.

In effect, every vector can be written as a linear combination of any 2 vectors.
[image]

Extending the same discussion to the complex plane, and treating the 90° line as the imaginary axis/dimension,
[image]

$2+3j$ can be written as the linear combination of 2 basis vectors $1=1+0j$ and $j=0+1j$ as
$$
    2+3j = x(1+0j) + y(0+1j)\qquad\text{ where }x=2\text{ and }y=3\,.
    $$
We make a special note here that in the case of the complex plane, $x$ and $y$ are real, whereas the basis vectors are complex numbers.

NOW, if we extend the same discussion to Quantum Computing to describe the state of a qubit, we describe the state of 1 qubit as $|q\rangle=\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$ where $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ can be explained according to another accept answer on Stack exchange for a different question. The numbers in notations like $|n\rangle$ are the analogues of indices in matrix notation. That is, $|0\rangle=e_0$,  $|1\rangle=e_1$, etc., where $e_n$ is the vector which has a $1$ in the $n$-th position and $0$ in the other entries. For qubits in quantum computers, the dimension is 2, so we have $|0\rangle=e_0=(1,0)$ and $|1\rangle=e_1=(0,1)$.
Accordingly - I am assuming –
\begin{align*}
    |0\rangle= e_0 &= (1,0) = (\,\text{Yes_it_is_Zero}\,,\, \text{No_it_is_not_1}\,)  \quad \text{ and}\\
    |1\rangle= e_1 &= (0,1) = (\,\text{No_it_is_not_Zero}\,,\, \text{Yes_it_is_1}\,)
\end{align*}
This also means that $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ themselves are not complex unless each of them are represented as a superposition of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

***Question 1:*** So, if $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ themselves are not complex, then, why do we need $x$ and $y$, i.e. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be complex here? This is different from the note earlier for the complex plane, where the basis was complex and the $x,y$ were real numbers. What is the need for probability amplitudes to be complex numbers? What is the intuition behind probability amplitudes $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be complex numbers?

***Question 2:*** What is the intuition behind probability amplitudes being squared to find probabilities of $|0\rangle$ state (with $|\alpha|^2$) or $|1\rangle$ state (with $|\beta|^2$).

***Question 3:*** And what is the meaning of pure states versus mixed states in my current framework of understanding?

Comment: @kvik To briefly answer 1, the importance of complex numbers is not in modeling a particular state-vector, it is in modeling the interaction between states and the different kinds of measurements that can be made or the interaction between multiple states within the same system. For example, the measurement of the [spin of an electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) within 3-dimensional space requires complex numbers.

Comment: @kvik To answer 3, mixed states (as represented by [density matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix)) represent a probability distribution over the possible configurations of a system rather than a single system's configuration. These are necessary, among other reasons, in order to understand the effect of "partial measurement" on a composite system (e.g. a system of multiple qubits).

Comment: This paper might be interesting to you: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401062

Comment: Also, it is better to split each of your 3 questions into separate posts. It will be quite hard for someone to comprehensively answer all three.